# Using jquery, find the div class that the top of the viewport is "inside"

Tags: jquery

I have a single-page website divided up like so:

```
<div class="splash-screen"> 
  <!--Content-->
</div>
<div class="about-us"> 
  <!--Content-->
</div>
<div class="contact-us"> 
  <!--Content-->
</div>
```

How can I find out where the viewer is currently at? A function that returns the name of the div the viewer is in.

I've tried using [jquery waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/), but it's approach is sort of the wrong angle. Waypoints triggers a function when the viewport enters a div. I want to find what div the viewport is entering programatically, so that I can adjust a menu-slider accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put an event listener on the window scroll. Each time the window scrolls we can check if the top of the body is under the top of each section (or within 100 pixels of the top of each section).

**HTML**

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section4">Section 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="section1" class="pageSection">
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
</div>
<div id="section2" class="pageSection">
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
</div>
<div id="section3" class="pageSection">
    <h2>Section 3</h2>
</div>
<div id="section4" class="pageSection">
    <h2>Section 4</h2>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var windowTop = Math.max($('body').scrollTop(), $('html').scrollTop());

    $('.pageSection').each(function (index) {
        if (windowTop > ($(this).position().top - 100))
        {
            $('#navigation a.current').removeClass('current');
            $('#navigation a:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('current');
        }
    });

}).scroll();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/63z9S/1/)**

Comment: Really good answer. The script accommodates for different div sizes, meaning it can be used on a data-base driven or adaptive website. Also, very each to implement!

Answer (score 1):

On load page, store both the top position, the bottom position and the class name of each div:

```
positions = {}

for $div in $('div')
  topPosition = $div.offset().top
  bottomPosition = topPosition + $div.outerHeight()
  positions[topPosition] = positions[bottomPosition] = $div.attr('class')
```

Storing both the top **and** the bottom position allow to be notified when a `div` is entered from below.

The positions object will be calculated only once and will look something like:

```
{
  0: 'splash-screen',
  400: 'splash-screen',
  401: 'about-us',
  801: 'about-us',
  802: 'contact-us',
  1202: 'contact-us'
}
```

Then listen to the window scroll event and just call:

```
$(window).scroll -> 
  return unless divClassName = positions[window.scrollY]
  console.log "Entering #{divClassName}!"
```

Edit in JavaScript:

```
var positions = {};

$('div').each(function(index) {
  var topPosition, bottomPosition;
  topPosition = $(this).offset().top;
  bottomPosition = topPosition + $(this).outerHeight();
  positions[topPosition] = positions[bottomPosition] = $(this).attr('class');
})

$(window).scroll(function(e){      
  if (positions[window.scrollY] == undefined) return;
  console.log('Entering ' + positions[window.scrollY] + '!');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/63z9S/3/ based on @3dgoo demo

```
//get all sections
var sections = $('.' + sectionClass);
//save each section top position and height along with id
for(var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++){
    var section = $(sections[i]);
    _items.push({
        id: section.attr('id'),
        top: section.offset().top,
        height: section.outerHeight()
    });
}


var wndTopPos = $(window).scrollTop(); //current window top position
var wndHeight = $(window).height();    //window height, could be stored somewhere
var wndBotPos = wndTopPos + wndHeight; //bottom window position
var sections  = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < _items.length; i++){
    //if top or bottom section position(border) lies between window top or bottom position(border)
    //-> its active section and
    //if window is inside one of the sections
    if(_items[i].top >= wndTopPos && 
            _items[i].top <= wndBotPos || 
        _items[i].top + _items[i].height >= wndTopPos &&
            _items[i].top + _items[i].height <= wndBotPos ||        
        _items[i].top <= wndTopPos && 
            _items[i].top + _items[i].height >= wndTopPos || 
        _items[i].top <= wndBotPos && 
            _items[i].top + _items[i].height >= wndBotPos){
                sections.push(_items[i].id)
    }
}

return sections;
```